# Can I watch pokemon for fun

Tags: halal-haram

I heard that pokemon is banned in Saudi arabia.i am a huge pokemon fan but now after hearing (I searched that in Islam Q&A (did not ask only searched)and the answer I didn't really understand)so much I just have one question:***Can I watch pokemon for fun?***

Answer (score -3):

No   , you can't watch pokemon. It is haram.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/61258)